# iPad App Crashing with NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to make my first cocos2d, chipmunk ipad app

I set a "ball" sprite in my .h file like this:

```
 // HelloWorld Layer 
 @interface
 HelloWorld : CCLayer {     
    cpSpace  *space;
    CCSprite *ball;     
 }
```

and I am moving it like this (upon a touch):

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for( UITouch *touch in touches ) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];         

        // Determine speed of the target
        int minDuration = 2.0;
        int maxDuration = 4.0;
        int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
        int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

        // Create the actions
        id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration 
                                            position:ccp(location.x, location.y)];
        id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
        [ball runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

        [ball retain]; 
    }
}
```

When I run with the debugger I get this:

```
2011-06-29 20:44:04.121 ballgame[3499:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HelloWorld spriteMoveFinished:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x605a3e0'
```

It appears to work for a couple touches and then it seems to crash, so perhaps its memory leak? Any suggestions or advice would really help, this is like my first app.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling a method (`spriteMoveFinished:`) on your `HelloWorld` object that doesn't exist. Did you make a `spriteMoveFinished:` method?

'Unrecognized selector sent' = calling a method that isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try debugging your app? Try NSZombie also according to your crash log one of your object is released and you called a function on that. Try NSZombieEnable in your environment flag.

Answer (score 2):

Did you define a `spriteMoveFinished:` method?  If not, define it.  If it already is then your HelloWorld object probably hasn't been retained anywhere.